# What is the preferred development environment for Salesforce.com?

Tags: ide, salesforce

What is the preferred development environment for Salesforce.com?  The training I have been taking says the Force.com IDE is preferred, yet I have heard that all the new features are going into the Developer Console web IDE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

within the Force.com platform you have the following options:

- Force.com IDE
- Developer Console (great tool, <del>but it's dramatically slowly</del> (**update**: after latest release DEveloper tool seems like a great and powerful development tool))
- your preferable text editor + ant migration tool
- [Brain Engine IDE](http://www.brainengine.net/)

from my point of view a combining Force.com IDE with migration tool and text editor (Sublime Text 2 for my case) and using from time to time Developer Console is the best way.

I have the following workflow:

- any deployment tasks should be performed by ant migration tool (CI tool might be useful here)
- apex/triggers - Force.com IDE + text editor
- VF - sf page editor within developer mode or Force.com IDE for really big pages

---

**Significant UPDATE:**

- Right now, the most useful and powerful tool from developer perspective is [MavensMate](http://mavensmate.com/) plugin for Sublime Text. But in a some cases this tool should be supplemented by Eclipse and Developer Console.

Comment: Interesting...  I had not yet heard of BrainEngine.  Very intriguing.  Also what is the benefit of using ant for deployments versus deploying right in the UI?

Comment: @JonMitchell, from my point of view the main benefit is the ability for using Continuous Integration servers like Jenkins or Cruise Control. The second benefit is the ability for running unit tests each time as you deploy code to sandbox or developer org. Also it provides a flexibility for your project by using additional ant plugins, etc.

Comment: Wow, the continuous integration is a world I didn't know existing.

Comment: One more IDE to give it a try - [The Welkin Suite](http://welkinsuite.com/). It's in Beta at the moment but already have some nice features like custom folders structure and so on.